# ARMv7 Assembly Language : How to add two uint32_t and return a uint64_t result

Tags: c, assembly, arm

I am a beginner tinkering with ARM7 Assembly Language programming and have been stuck on this one issue.

I am trying to implement a function in C that takes two unsigned 32 bit vars (uint32_t A and uint32_t B), adds them together and then returns a uint64_t value where the sum contains the carry.

I have included both my C code and ARM7 Assembly Language code below. However, my code doesn't output the correct value; which is probably due to my ASM instructions. Also, I am running Linux with a 32 bit machine.

addVal.s (code below)

```
.global addVal 

.text

addVal:
    ADD R0, R0, R1
    ADC R0, R1 
    BX LR
```

addVal.c (code below)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

extern uint64_t addVal(uint32_t x, uint32_t y);

int main()
{
  uint32_t a, b;
  uint64_t c;
  a = 4000000000;
  b = 1000000000;
  c = addVal(a,b);
  printf("a = %u\r\n", a);
  printf("b = %u\r\n", b);
  printf("c = a + b = %llu\r\n", c);
  return 0;

}
```

compiled on command line using

```
as -o addVal addVal.o addVal.s
gcc -o addVal addVal_s.o addVal.c
./addVal
```

Comment: Just an FYI: gcc has functions for adding numbers with carry.  Check out [Arithmetic with Overflow Checking](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Integer-Overflow-Builtins.html).  Using builtins like this can result in better code (ie no need for call/return, support for constants, cross platform support, etc).  Doesn't help if your goal is to learn asm, but using asm should typically be your last choice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ADC R0, R1` is wrong.

As `uint64_t` exceeds the size of a single register, it's spread into a subsequent range of registers. The low word resides in `R0`, high word in `R1`. So the target register for `ADC` needs to be `R1`.

Second problem is that you don't want to add the original low word of `R1` into the result high word, but only the carry bit. So you can just clear `R1` first.

```
.text
.arm
.global addVal 
.func addVal
addVal:
    ADDS R0, R0, R1
    MOV R1, #0
    ADC R1, R1, #0
    BX LR
```

Comment: Thank you for helping; that logic makes complete sense. It appears after I have made this change I still get a random value. I'm trying to get 5 billion to (exceeds unsigned 32 bit range) but I get a random value that is in the trillions. Is there possibly another register I am not accounting for? The concept you displayed makes sense though.

Comment: @SamT Honestly no idea, the assembly looks correct. If anything, I could imagine the calling convention is somehow still wrong. If it's random, something has been left uninitialized.

Please check the assembly which gcc has created for `main`, so you can see how the function is actually called.

Comment: Sure thing! Thank you for your time and assistance.

Comment: Thank you both! I can't tell you how much I struggled with this. The answer above correctly solved the issue and I got 5 billion for the output. I will study this in depth to further understand ARM ASM. Thank you again.